# Python text menu that runs simple shell script

Tags: python, shell, menu, raspberry-pi

I have no idea how to go about this so I'm not sure where to start.

Basically I want to write a python script that will present a user with a list of items that can be toggled through and selected using the arrow keys and enter key. If python isn't able to do this is there another language that can ?

The selection made will then run a simple line of shell script (in raspbian)

The idea is that I'll use this a list of games that my raspberry pi will run using MAME. i.e a nice simple way of selecting a game as opposed to writing in the line of code every time.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to look at `curses`. Search Google for tutorials, e.g., [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python). 
It's a nice library to create an interface as you describe here.

When you have your minimalistic GUI running, use the `subprocess`-module to launch your scripts, e.g.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["my_script.sh","parameter1","parameter2"])
```

**Edit**

Seems like curses doesn't support selectable lists, but ncurses does. In the Debian repositories, there is `python-urwid`, some Python-bindings to ncurses.

An example would be:

```
import urwid
import subprocess

games = {"Game1":"script_name1.sh",
         "Game2":"script_name2.sh",
         "Game3":"script_name3.sh",
         "Game4":"script_name4.sh",
         "Game5":"script_name5.sh",}

class ItemWidget (urwid.WidgetWrap):

    def __init__ (self, id, description):
        self.id = id
        self.content = description
        self.item = [
            ('fixed', 15, urwid.Padding(urwid.AttrWrap(
                urwid.Text('%s:' % str(id)), 'body', 'focus'), left=2)),
            urwid.AttrWrap(urwid.Text('%s' % description), 'body', 'focus'),
        ]
        w = urwid.Columns(self.item)
        self.__super.__init__(w)

    def selectable (self):
        return True

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        return key

def main ():
    palette = [
        ('body','dark cyan', '', 'standout'),
        ('focus','dark red', '', 'standout'),
        ('head','light red', 'black'),
        ]

    def keystroke (input):
        if input in ('q', 'Q'):
            raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

        if input is 'enter':
            view.set_header(urwid.AttrWrap(urwid.Text("selected"), 'head'))
            focus = listbox.get_focus()[0].content
            try:
                subprocess.call(games[focus])
            except OSError, ose:
                view.set_header(urwid.AttrWrap(urwid.Text(
                    'error starting %s: %s' % (str(focus), str(ose))), 'head'))

    items = []
    game_keys = sorted(games.keys())
    for i, k in enumerate(game_keys):
        items.append(ItemWidget(i, k))

    header = urwid.AttrMap(urwid.Text('selected:'), 'head')
    listbox = urwid.ListBox(urwid.SimpleListWalker(items))
    view = urwid.Frame(urwid.AttrWrap(listbox, 'body'), header=header)
    loop = urwid.MainLoop(view, palette, unhandled_input=keystroke)
    loop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is adapted from [nicosphere](http://www.nicosphere.net/selectable-list-with-urwid-for-python-2542/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "," to "as" at line 45 to put it to work at python 3.10:

```
        except OSError as ose:
            view.set_header(urwid.AttrWrap(urwid.Text(
                'error starting %s: %s' % (str(focus), str(ose))), 'head'))
```